# Link Mini Panel thumbnail formatter to node

Tags: views, panels

Working on a site that shows images and video with a Mini Panel formatter in a View withe File Entity and Media modules. The Mini Panel has a piece of content of file display that shows an Image display as well as Vimeo Video and YouTube. The Image display settings uses an Image style.

How do I link the media from the mini-panel to the referencing entity? (User clicks on the thumbnail in the view listing and is taken to the node's path).

Comment: i have changed the view to display rendered file and installed https://drupal.org/project/file_entity_link. this is an incomplete solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the view display page and click on the field of your thumbnail, on the settings page scroll down and you should see a drop-down with title of **Link image to**. Choose content and save.

Comment: Content fields have the option, "Link this field to the original piece of content" But the Media field does not.

Answer (score 0):

To  link the media to the node,you need to follow some steps as:-

1. Edit the view which contains images and videos which are to be linked to a node.
2. In the fields section,Just Click on the field which would link to some node.

3.1 In the REWRITE RESULT's tab,check the checkbox :Output this field as a link and specify the destination url to which you want to link to.

3.2. or to link the formatter, just click on the field and in the LINK IMAGE TO and select a option to which you want your formatter to be linked to.

Comment: Thanks neetu, can you suggest the token replacement for option 3.1? I do not understand 3.2, but it got me wanted to have the mini panel set up to link to content so can easily have consistency a cross my views.